# How to manipulate a table with postgres without define a Sequelize Model

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have created a 'user' table directly in postgres shell, and all i need is to manipulate (CRUD) the data without have to create a model  like this:

```js
const User = sequelize.define('user', {
  firstName: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
  },
  lastName: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
  },
});
```

I've searched a lot in the documentation, but what I've seen so far, I must create a Model.
Is there a way I can work without creating the Model?

Comment: Don't name a table `user`. That wull cause trouble, since `user` is a reserved SQL keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Raw queries](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/raw-queries.html) to manipulate the data without having to create a model.

For example:

We have `User` table in the database:

```
node-sequelize-examples=# select * from "User";
 UserId |          UserEmail           |                             UserAvatar                              
--------+------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------
      1 | Korey31@hotmail.com          | https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/markretzloff/128.jpg
      2 | Tevin_Wintheiser81@yahoo.com | https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/faisalabid/128.jpg
      3 | Cody47@yahoo.com             | https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/sur4dye/128.jpg
(3 rows)
```

Use raw query to get all users:

```js
import { sequelize } from '../../db';
import { QueryTypes } from 'sequelize';

sequelize.query('select * from "User"', { type: QueryTypes.SELECT }).then(console.log);
```

Logs:

```
Executing (default): select * from "User"
[ { UserId: 1,
    UserEmail: 'Korey31@hotmail.com',
    UserAvatar:
     'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/markretzloff/128.jpg' },
  { UserId: 2,
    UserEmail: 'Tevin_Wintheiser81@yahoo.com',
    UserAvatar:
     'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/faisalabid/128.jpg' },
  { UserId: 3,
    UserEmail: 'Cody47@yahoo.com',
    UserAvatar:
     'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/sur4dye/128.jpg' } ]
```

Comment: Thank you very much @slideshowp2, this is what I was looking for.